# UIAlertController does not show when a var reaches a certain value

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, var, uialertcontroller

I'd like to get an alert to show when 3 specific value is reached,

here's my code

```
func SectionAlert () {

    if (section1score >= 10){

        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "\((section1score as NSNumber).stringValue)", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            action -> Void in
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if (section2score >= 10){

    } else if (section3score >= 10){

    }

}
```

My App updates each sections value when a cell is tapped in the TableView

My code does not show any error but it does not give me my alert when my value reaches 10 and over

any ideas??

thanks !

Comment: Do you call this function when a cell is tapped?

Comment: no, but I thought if it depends on the cell value, and that my function when tapped modifies my var value. It should run by itself? Am I wrong?